# Which D&D board game is best for beginners and can I create custom hero?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e, dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons

as the question says, I am considering buying the D&D board game. I can't decide which game to buy, but I've narrowed it down to The Legend of Drizzt, Wrath of Ashardalon, Temple of Elemental Evil, and Castle Ravenloft. My question is, which of these games is best for beginners, and can I make custom heroes in them? Thanks for your answers:)

Comment: Welcome to the stack KobacYea, take the [tour] when you have a moment. Unfortunately, recommendation/shopping questions, as well as questions about board games, are off topic here, so this question will be closed. However, you may be able to find some answers on a more traditional forum, see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) for our curated list.

Comment: Is the end goal to get into D&D or the D&D based board games specifically? If the former I think there is some help we can offer, though I'm not sure how it forms as a stack question

Comment: The goal is to get into D&D but for starter my friends and i are considering board games, hence the questions

Comment: The Board games have nothing to do with the adventure lines of similar or same names.